# How to use MakeHuman materials?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, external-applications

I made a model from MakeHuman. I want to add the color of the eyes, of the skin....
I have these materials on the right side:

[image]

I don't know how to use them.
Thank you

Comment: Can I use the materials from MakeHuman? I mean I selected the king of skin. Can I use it in Blender?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When exporting from Makehuman, I choose the ".dae" file format, and then import this into Blender

Upon importing into Blender, my scene looks like this:

[image: Imported model]

I then switch to the "Material" view, which changes my model to a brighter shade of grey:

[image: Material view]

Next, I go to the "Materials" tab, and click "Use Nodes"

[image: Use nodes]

I then click the little dot to the right of the "Color" widget, and choose "Image Texture" from the drop down:

[image: Image Texture]

From the little drop down to the left of the "Open" button, I then choose the skin texture, since my currently selected mesh is the body mesh:

[image: Select image]

My mesh now looks like this:

[image: Final skin look]

I then select the eyes, which are part of a separate mesh, and repeat the above steps; click "Use Nodes", click to the right of "Color" and choose "Image Texture", click the drop down to the left of "Open" and choose the texture for the eyes.

Does this help at all? If you need to know how to create and assign custom materials within Blender, then I suggest you look at the following links:

[Blender Render]

http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/learning-materials-textures-images.php

[Cycles]

http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-cycles/

There's also cycles-specific and blender render-specific documentation here:

https://www.blender.org/manual/render/index.html

Comment: When I choose .dae format. Bender doesn't find it  out. Maybe I need to select something in UsePreferences.

Comment: You should be able to import .dae by navigating to File > Import > Collada (Default) (.dae) and then selecting the file in the file browser. Have you definitely exported the mesh as a .dae from MakeHuman?

Comment: Yes, I import  in Collada. I choose my file and I select Import Collada. My blender is 2.74 and it doesn't do anything. I am in Cycles Render.

Comment: Is your scene completely empty? Delete any exisitng meshes from your scene and try again. I've noticed that the MakeHuman models are quite small when they are imported, so they may be contained within an existing mesh in your scene. Also, what layer are you on? Press '1' on your keyboard to switch to layer 1 - does the model show up now? Can you upload the .dae file that you are trying to import? Or can you upload the blend file that you've imported the model into? I am also using Blender 2.74

Comment: I did it. I followed your steps with .bend format. It works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries mate, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: @Meri, you should [Accept an answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your question ;-)